# What's the most appropriate NLS_SORT parameter to cover all/most European languages?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, nls

I'm developing an Oracle 11g-based application which is likely to be used by clients in many different countries (mostly European). I want the program to change its NLS_SORT so that it's case insensitive on startup using the `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT='???';` command.

I'm going to have a config file which contains the `NLS_SORT` setting the user wants to use so it is editable, but I want a default which will cover European languages. Which is the best one to choose?

Comment: This is a good starting read for NLS stuff http://www.orafaq.com/node/999

Comment: Thanks for this - I've found this list of possible values for the NLS_SORT parameter http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10749/applocal.htm#637234 Which one should I use by default? LATIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WEST_EUROPEAN would seem to be the obvious choice, but there is no default that lets you avoid setting it on an individual language basis.